# Add id to element with javascript using django field

Tags: javascript, django

I have a problem creating id's for my elements. We use django as framework and I create element id's from the field name as this:

```
<tr class="issueRow" id="{{field.auto_id}}">
```

However, some field.auto_id's have blank spaces in them, this causes problems later on when looping through elements with document.getElementById.

So, my question is, how can I trim away those blank spaces from my new id?
I have a function that simply removes the blank spaces but I can't seem to find the correct way to call the function with a django field as parameter since 
 `id="{{TrimID({{field.auto_id}})}}"` gives a parsing error

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Django's built-in [cut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) filter here.

In your example it would be:

`<tr class="issueRow" id="{{field.auto_id|cut:" "}}">`

If **value** is **"String with spaces"**, the output will be **"Stringwithspaces"**.

P.S.

As far as I know *auto_id* should not have spaces. Maybe you can find the root cause and fix it so this template filter would not be necessary.